# PHP Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Tags: php, mysql

PHP Warning:  mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource at line x. 
I checked for all single quotes missing and sql link .

```
$v = html_entity_decode($v);
            $query_1 = sprintf("select part_of_speech_id from word_parts_of_speech where word = '%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($v));
            $res = Commons::query($query_1) ;
            if(mysql_num_rows($res) != 0){
                    while  ($row  =  mysql_fetch_assoc($res))  {

                            if($row['part_of_speech_id']!=15){//see table down for reference

                                    $query_url = "insert into freetext_keywords(RANDOM_ID,URL,TAG_NAME,KEYWORD) values('$random_id','$url','$tagName','$v') on duplicate key update WEIGHT = WEIGHT + 1";
                                    $result = Commons::query($query_url);
                            }
                    }
            }else{
                    $query_url = "insert into freetext_keywords(RANDOM_ID,URL,TAG_NAME,KEYWORD) values('$random_id','$url','$tagName','$v') on duplicate key update WEIGHT = WEIGHT + 1";
                    $result = Commons::query($query_url);
            }


    }
```

Comment: please add your code so we know where to debug.

Comment: your query may be wrong ..use mysql_error to see the error

Comment: You might be using `mysql_num_rows()` on update or delete statement or your query has a syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just echo the MySql query in php and run against the database in phpmyadmin (I hope you are using phpmyadmin to access your database)

And see if the query execute well and return result. If it shows any errors, please correct your query accordingly.

```
<?php

echo $query_1 = sprintf("select part_of_speech_id from word_parts_of_speech where word = '%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($v));

?>
```

Copy the query from the browser and run directly against database.